# Why can't Azure App Service find my GoDaddy certificate?

Tags: .net, azure, asp.net-core, azure-web-app-service, identityserver4

I have an Azure App Service running a .NET Core 3.1 application, using IdentityServer4 for authentication.

My `appsettings.json` file looks like this:

```
...
"IdentityServer": {
  "Clients": {
    "MyApp": {
      "Profile": "IdentityServerSPA"
    }
  },
  "Key": {
    "Type": "Store",
    "StoreName": "My",
    "StoreLocation": "CurrentUser",
    "Name": "CN=mydomain.com"
  }
},
...
```

I created a certificate via GoDaddy with the following (fake) values:

- Thumbprint: `my-thumbprint`
- Subject Name: `app.mydomain.com,www.app.mydomain.com`

This certificate was uploaded to my App Service as a private key certificate, and also stored in Azure Key Vault (during the custom domain binding configuration).

In my App Service Configuration settings, I have the following set:

- `WEBSITE_LOAD_CERTIFICATES`: `my-thumbprint`
- `IdentityServer__Key__Name`: `CN=app.mydomain.com,www.app.mydomain.com`

My app fails to start. Starting the Azure App Service console and running the command

```
dotnet myapp.dll
```

results in the following stacktrace:

```
Unhandled exception. System.InvalidOperationException: Couldn't find a valid certificate with subject 'CN=app.addtheand.com,www.app.addtheand.com' on the 'CurrentUser\My'
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.ApiAuthorization.IdentityServer.SigningKeysLoader.LoadFromStoreCert(String subject, String storeName, StoreLocation storeLocation, DateTimeOffset currentTime)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.ApiAuthorization.IdentityServer.ConfigureSigningCredentials.LoadKey()
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.ApiAuthorization.IdentityServer.ConfigureSigningCredentials.Configure(ApiAuthorizationOptions options)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.Options.OptionsFactory`1.Create(String name)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.Options.OptionsManager`1.<>c__DisplayClass5_0.<Get>b__0()
   at System.Lazy`1.ViaFactory(LazyThreadSafetyMode mode)
   at System.Lazy`1.ExecutionAndPublication(LazyHelper executionAndPublication, Boolean useDefaultConstructor)
   at System.Lazy`1.CreateValue()
   at System.Lazy`1.get_Value()
   at Microsoft.Extensions.Options.OptionsCache`1.GetOrAdd(String name, Func`1 createOptions)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.Options.OptionsManager`1.Get(String name)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.Options.OptionsManager`1.get_Value()
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.IdentityServerBuilderConfigurationExtensions.<>c.<AddClients>b__7_1(IServiceProvider sp)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitFactory(FactoryCallSite factoryCallSite, RuntimeResolverContext context)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteVisitor`2.VisitCallSiteMain(ServiceCallSite callSite, TArgument argument)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitCache(ServiceCallSite callSite, RuntimeResolverContext context, ServiceProviderEngineScope serviceProviderEngine, RuntimeResolverLock lockType)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitRootCache(ServiceCallSite singletonCallSite, RuntimeResolverContext context)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteVisitor`2.VisitCallSite(ServiceCallSite callSite, TArgument argument)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitConstructor(ConstructorCallSite constructorCallSite, RuntimeResolverContext context)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteVisitor`2.VisitCallSiteMain(ServiceCallSite callSite, TArgument argument)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitDisposeCache(ServiceCallSite transientCallSite, RuntimeResolverContext context)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteVisitor`2.VisitCallSite(ServiceCallSite callSite, TArgument argument)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitConstructor(ConstructorCallSite constructorCallSite, RuntimeResolverContext context)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteVisitor`2.VisitCallSiteMain(ServiceCallSite callSite, TArgument argument)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitDisposeCache(ServiceCallSite transientCallSite, RuntimeResolverContext context)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteVisitor`2.VisitCallSite(ServiceCallSite callSite, TArgument argument)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.Resolve(ServiceCallSite callSite, ServiceProviderEngineScope scope)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.DynamicServiceProviderEngine.<>c__DisplayClass1_0.<RealizeService>b__0(ServiceProviderEngineScope scope)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.ServiceProviderEngine.GetService(Type serviceType, ServiceProviderEngineScope serviceProviderEngineScope)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.ServiceProviderEngineScope.GetService(Type serviceType)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder.IdentityServerApplicationBuilderExtensions.TestService(IServiceProvider serviceProvider, Type service, ILogger logger, String message, Boolean doThrow)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder.IdentityServerApplicationBuilderExtensions.Validate(IApplicationBuilder app)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder.IdentityServerApplicationBuilderExtensions.UseIdentityServer(IApplicationBuilder app, IdentityServerMiddlewareOptions options)
```

What am I missing?

My app runs as expected in DEV mode, which uses the IdentityServer configuration in `appsettings.json` without modification, loading/using a different self-signed certificate.

**UPDATE**

I checked if the certificate was loaded to the App Service *machine*, and it wasn't found.

Steps to find this:

1. From the App Service in the Azure portal, start kudo
2. In kudo, select Debug Console -> Powershell
3. Run the following command: `dir cert:\localmachine\my`

**UPDATE 2**

Since I'm trying to load the cert via CurrentUser, I instead ran the following command in the powershell terminal: `dir cert:\CurrentUser\My`, finding that the Subject didn't match what I saw in the Azure portal.

- SUBJECT IN PORTAL: `app.mydomain.com,www.app.mydomain.com`
- SUBJECT IN OUTPUT: `CN=app.mydomain.com, OU=Domain Co...`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following up on **Update 2**...

The mismatch in *Subject* that I was seeing in the Azure Portal when viewing the certificate via the UI versus what I was seeing when running the `dir cert:\CurrentUser\my` command via kudo's Powershell console was the source of my problem.

To fix, I changed my configuration value for `IdentityServer__Key__Name` from the **subject according to the Portal UI**:

```
CN=app.mydomain.com,www.app.mydomain.com
```

to the **subject according to the command above**:

```
CN=app.mydomain.com, OU=Domain Control Validated
```